# Generate more than 1000 ticks using chart.js

Tags: typescript, chart.js

I'm trying to configure a chart using `chart.js`. The problem that I am facing is that when I set the ticks configuration `stepSize` to 0.04 in the *X* scale, I get a warning in the console that says: *scales.x.ticks.stepSize: 0.04 would result generating up to 1027 ticks. Limiting to 1000*

Internally, the `LinearScaleBase` has a function called `getTickLimit`  that limits the ticks to 1000.
I have tried to set the `maxTicksLimit` to a higher number in the configuration, but it does not work.

Is there a way to override the function `getTickLimit`? Maybe I'am missing some configuration?
It is important to show the ticks every 0.04 because of the information that I'm trying to display.
This is a snippet of the configuration of my chart:

```
const config: any = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
                data: data.ecgData,
                borderColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
                borderWidth: 1,
                radius: 0,
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            }
        },
        scales: {
            x: {
                type: 'linear',
                position: 'bottom',
                grid: {
                    display: true,
                    drawOnChartArea: true,
                    drawTicks: true,
                },
                ticks: {
                    display: true,
                    autoSkip: false,
                    maxTicksLimit: 5000,
                    stepSize: 0.04
                }
            },
            y: {
                grid: {
                    display: true,
                    drawOnChartArea: true,
                    drawTicks: true
                },
                ticks: {
                    // forces step size to be 50 units
                    stepSize: 0.2,
                    display: true,
                    maxTicksLimit: 3000,
                    autoSkip: false,
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you are using chartjs 4 since ticks in chartjs 3 are configured in the `options.scales.yAxes.ticks` property instead of `options.scales.y.ticks`.

In the x axis:

- calculate your own ticks and assign the array to `data.labels` as the source of information for ticks.
- use `options.scales.x.ticks.autoSkip: false` to ensure the ticks aren't reduced

Adding your own ticks in the y axis is slightly more complicated:

- calculate your own y ticks array with each tick saved as an object with `value` property, e.g. [{value: 0}, {value: 0.2}, {value: 0.4}].
- add `options.scales.y.afterBuildTicks` which accepts a callback function and reassign `axis.ticks`
- you can check that you indeed have > 1,000 ticks by using `options.scales.y.callback` to and log in the console (tick.length)

Code Example

```js
import "./styles.css";
import Chart from "chart.js/auto";

import { default as $ } from "./lib/jq";

let SIZE_OF_DATASET = 1500;
let X_STEP_SIZE = 0.04;
let Y_STEP_SIZE = 0.2;

let xTicks = [];
let yTicks = [];
let data = [];
for (let i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_DATASET; i++) {
  xTicks.push((i * X_STEP_SIZE).toFixed(2));
  data.push(Math.random() * 250);
}

for (let i = 0; i < 1250; i++) {
  yTicks.push({ value: i * Y_STEP_SIZE.toFixed(2) });
}

let ctx = $("#myChart");
new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: xTicks,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "test",
        data: data,
        borderColor: "rgb(0, 0, 0)",
        borderWidth: 1,
        radius: 0
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "Custom Chart Title"
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        ticks: {
          autoSkip: false // prevent skipping of ticks in x-axis
        }
      },
      y: {
        afterBuildTicks: (axis) => { // reassign the ticks automatically calculated for you
          axis.ticks = yTicks;
        },
        grid: {
          display: false,
          drawOnChartArea: true,
          drawTicks: true
        },
        ticks: {
          // stepSize: 0.2,
          display: true,
          autoSkip: false,
          beginAtZero: true,
          callback: (tickValue, i, ticks) => { // validate number of ticks
            console.log(ticks.length);
            return tickValue;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Here's a [CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-moore-pyh8pj?file=/src/index.js:0-1357)